# Can I Install Visual C++ Redistributable In a Particular folder?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, registry, redistributable

Is there any way to install **Visual C++ Redistributable** to a folder rather then windows folder and save related registry entries in a .reg file. So that when i will import that .reg file windows will load that Visual C++ Redistributable and use it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Why do you need this?

Comment: I am in a project of making portable server with `nginx` and `apache` it starts with `vbs -> CLI php`. But it is not working under a system which does not include `Visual C++ Redistributable` . So if i could point it somewhere in a folder and before startup i can configure it, i think it will work.

Comment: Just ship the redistributables with your application. Once it's installed it will work automatically. You need to read more how Visual C++ Redistributable package works particularly and [WoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows) in general.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ supports xcopy deployment, no installation required.  Just provide the DLL's in an [Application Local Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293565.aspx).